# Recursion countup with string output

Tags: python, string, recursion

I need to do a countup value that prints as a string  -- so if the user would enter 5 it would count up from 1 -- ' 1 2 3 4 5' in a string and not seperate lines. This is what i have for a basic recursion function that counts up however it is not giving me the output of a string. Any help would be much appreciated

```
def countup(N, n=0):
    print(n)
    if n < N:
        countup(N, n + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return a string, think about returning strings. The first part of your result is `n` converted to a string: `str(n)`. While you're not yet done, you append a space followed by the *countup* of the rest of the numbers. Like so:

```
def countup(N, n=1):
    res = str(n)
    if n < N:
        res += ' ' + countup(N, n + 1)
    return res

print(countup(5))
```

Another version, without the need of a local variable, is:

```
def countup(N, n=1):
    if n < N:
        return str(n) + ' ' + countup(N, n + 1)
    else:
        return str(n)
```

Comment: can I ask what "res" means?

Comment: `res` is a local variable with the temporary result. It's a string where you build up the result.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `str.join`? No recursion needed here.

```
def countup(N, n=1):
    return ' '.join(map(str, range(n, N)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For start, this is a basically a duplicate of [python recursive function that prints from 0 to n?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17127355/) and [recursion, Python, countup, countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46201436/)

Change your ending of the print with `print(n, end = ' ')` to avoid the new line. See [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/)

Also, your default argument should be `n=1` to comply with `it would count up from 1` assuming the call of `countup(5)`

```py
def countup(N, n=1):
    print(n, end = ' ')
    if n < N:
        countup(N, n + 1)
```